# Exchange Web Services - load outlook all day event appointment

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am trying to fetch an all-day calendar appointment from outlook using EWS.

I've set UTC timezone in the code:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013, TimeZoneInfo.Utc)
```

And I've set UTC in the outlook calendar settings:

[image]

Here is my appointment in outlook calendar:
[image]

Why does EWS return appointment with **start date** equals to 7:00 AM of 4th April and **end date** equals to 7:00 AM of 5th April?

Comment: What timezone was the appointment created in ? just changing your timezone won't affect existing appointments that where created in another timezone

Comment: You are right, I created a new all-day appointment and EWS returned me expected start and end dates. It's confusing that the all-day appointment is not shifted explicity after the timezone was changed.